# Receiving strings through uart interrupts

Tags: string, uart, atmel

I'm trying to send some strings to my board (Atmel SAM3U). I'm doing it through the uart using interrupts. The issue is that it doesn't receive the whole string, but only the last character.

This is my code:

```
void UART_Handler(void){

uint32_t status = uart_get_status(UART); //gets uart status register

if(status & UART_SR_RXRDY){ //if there is a new character arrived

    uart_read(UART,&UART_RX_Buffer[UART_RX_Index]); //reads the character in a global buffer
    printf("\n\r ho letto %c; rxindex: %d\n\r",UART_RX_Buffer[UART_RX_Index],UART_RX_Index); //writes what he read

    if(UART_RX_Buffer[UART_RX_Index]== '#'){ //if the read character is # the string is complete and ready to be parsed
        UART_RX_Complete=1;
    }

    UART_RX_Index=(UART_RX_Index+1)%BUFF_SIZE; //increments the buffer index
}
```

The interrupt is set each time a byte is received.
If I send one charcter at time the code works very well, but I need to send the whole string at once.

Comment: Are you calling printf from an interrupt handler? Is that safe on your platform?

Comment: why shouldn't be safe? the printf sends the data through uart... However i'll try it!

Comment: incredible it really was that! Thanks a lot man :))